# Where to place configuration file / security?

Tags: java, security, properties

I have a global `configuration file` that contains properties like webservice-endpoints, user and passwords, auto-mailer, smtp ports, etc. This file is currently just placed in the root of my project.

When I hand my software to other users:

- where should I place this file so that it cannot be directly inspected?
- how could I additionally secure this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `Jasypt` do perform at least a step in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I think so If person is putting your project on to box, that means he can see these detail. if you want to really secure it  then you can decode the strings and in code you encode this..